# Alfresco workflow get triggered multiple times

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-webscripts

I am facing problem in triggering workflow.

I have applied  rule on a Folder

Definition of rule :

i)  When Item are created on enter this folder
ii) Name End With .xml
iii)Execute Script

Script is

```
function startWorkflow()
{
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$Excel_initial_service";
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "Excel initial      service workflow for : " + document.name;
var futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 1);
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = futureDate;
return workflow.execute(document);
}

function main()
{
startWorkflow();
}

main();
```

and my workflow definition is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"   xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">

<process id="Excel_initial_service" name="Excel Initial Service"    isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
 .
 .
 .
 .

<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:class="*">  </serviceTask>
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

The problem i am facing is service task is getting triggered multiple times for single file entered in the folder and its not getting stopped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<process id="***" name="Excel Generation Service" isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="starteventexcel1" name="Start"></startEvent>

<intermediateCatchEvent id="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel1" name="TimerCatchEvent1">
  <timerEventDefinition>
    <timeDuration>PT10S</timeDuration>
  </timerEventDefinition>
</intermediateCatchEvent>

<serviceTask id="servicetaskexcel1" name="Service Task" activiti:class="***"></serviceTask>

<intermediateCatchEvent id="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel2" name="TimerCatchEvent2">
  <timerEventDefinition>
    <timeDuration>PT10S</timeDuration>
  </timerEventDefinition>
</intermediateCatchEvent>



<endEvent id="endeventexcel1" name="End"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flowexcel1" sourceRef="starteventexcel1" targetRef="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flowexcel2" sourceRef="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel1" targetRef="servicetaskexcel1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flowexcel3" sourceRef="servicetaskexcel1" targetRef="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel2"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flowexcel4" sourceRef="timerintermediatecatcheventexcel2" targetRef="endeventexcel1"></sequenceFlow>

</process>
```

Comment: Are you performing some operations in script task??

Comment: you are taking about service task?? In my script i am executing a workflow **activiti$Excel_initial_service** In the service task of workflow i am generating some excel files

Comment: Can you add the full BPMN file to your question?

Comment: @izodev added BPMN file.. Also i analyze that my service task is taking some time and alfresco default behavior is to run the task if it is not get completed in certain period of time... do you have any idea how to override that default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The first intermediateCatchEvent here will execute your service task every 10 sec. Why using it?

Answer (score 0):

this answer may this will help you.

The class to use is the ClockUtil which changes the internal clock of the engine.

That being said, I checked your test and I saw that you are using the

```
ProcessEngine eng = ProcessEngineConfiguration
       .createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration()
       .buildProcessEngine();
```

To get the process engine. That will give you a default engine, with the job executor disabled. The job executor is needed for timer execution. Add following line to building the process engine to make it work:

```
setJobExecutorActivate(true);
```

You can refer this question https://community.alfresco.com/thread/219801-problem-with-intermediatecatchevent

you will find some code on github as explained in above referred question https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/test/java/org/activiti/engine/test/bpmn/event/timer/IntermediateTimerEventTest.java

Comment: Class mentioned in my BPMN file is implementing JavaDelegate .
I am not building any process engine. I'm using ServiceRegistry to get the NodeRef.

    ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl config =     Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
    ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) config.getBeans()
    .get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);`

Comment: Class mentioned in my BPMN file is implementing JavaDelegate .
I am not building any process engine. I'm using ServiceRegistry to get the NodeRef.

`ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl config =     Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) config.getBeans()
.get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);`

I didn't get where to add **setJobExecutorActivate(true);**